# PathMatcher in java

Tags: java

I have few questions from the below snippet

```
package com.concretepage.io.file;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class PathMatcherExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
        PathMatcher pathMatcher = fileSystem.getPathMatcher("glob:D:/**/*.java");
        Path path = Paths.get("D:/cp/PathMatcherExample.java");
        System.out.println(pathMatcher.matches(path));
    }
}
```

What is /**/* in the above ? I have read the following while I was doing some research on it:
* It matches zero , one or more than one characters. While matching, it will not cross directories boundaries. 
** It does the same as * but it crosses the directory boundaries.

But still unable to understand.

Thanks !!

Comment: In other words, ** will match files in an infinite number of directories below the base directory. * will only match files in the base directory.

Comment: Does the [documentation for getPathMatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-) make it any clearer?

Answer (score 0):

in common, asterics (*) means "any element"
double asterics in this case means "zero, one or amount of directories"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29